# What is the AlertOverride class used for in WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, alert

In Selenium 2.0 there is a class I've seen used with WebDriverCommandProcessor called AlertOveride. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find any documentation around this class, does anyone have any knowledge of what the class is meant to be used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the JavaScript in the file it seems that this class is responsible for overriding the alert and confirm boxes that we would typically see when invoked in the application under test. The way selenium works it was unable to interact with those modal boxes, hence the need to override their defaults. I don't see a way to override that functionality (although it might be doable with a DesiredCapability).

I'm guessing that one of the first things the WebDriver instance does upon loading a page is invoking the methods in the AlertOverride class, so that we can get a handle on alerts/confirmations as soon as possible. This would also make sense as to why we can't get a handle on confirmation boxes that are created on the onload functions.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something to this effect, but I assumed that the native behavior could have been set as a flag in a webdriver instance since installing an override seemed a bit excess since it seems like this would be needed to be done for many cases.