# Java, Selenium & Firefox Driver - driver.switchTo().alert() hangs on alert dialog. why?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

Scenario: selenium, java, firefox and alerts
So, I wrote some time back code to deal with an alert while crawling websites.

This sort of code is easily found when searching for selenium and alerts ..

```
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("No alert available: " + url);
    }
```

This seemed to work for the a couple test cases I had. One is the tomcat home page, on it you get a popup if you click 'status' for example.

Now I bumped into a dialog that blocks the above code. the switchTo() returns a TargetLocator but alert() on that locator blocks and never returns.

The links that triggers that dialog is http://www.fcb.com/news/rss.

Also, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356193/what-is-the-alertoverride-class-used-for-in-webdriver) post I found a comment saying "we can't get a handle on confirmation boxes that are created on the onload functions" I wonder what that means but my reputation is so low I can't comment yet :).

Also, as pointed out in the first answer, both the problematic dialog and the one that works are "authentication" alerts. I don't want to authenticate.

So, to recap, the ask is why does the TargetLocator.alert() call block? My ultimate goal is to close any such dialog I may encounter after driver.get(url).

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Cristian

p.s. regarding the duplicate tag, I don't think it's a duplicate. The code suggested there does not work either. One of the main objectives for my question is to understand why this popup blocks on the call to alert()

Comment: you can use alert for confirmation windows....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

As per link you provided http://www.fcb.com/news/rss, on navigating to this, it displaying authentication popup. its not alerts that's the reason you are facing issue..

check this:[Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

if it not what you looking for, please explain the issue as i am not able to comment to get more explanation.

Thank you,
Murali

Comment: Right, it's an authentication pop-up. But I thought it would be detected as an "alert". I don'y care about authenticating on that page. I just want to close it, get over it. The link referred by you also calls such a dialog an alert.

Comment: @Cristian the HTTP authentication popup cannot be directly manipulated with selenium, it is not an alert in selenium terms.

Comment: @Cristian: Then you can use keyevents in selenium or Robot class in Java to simulate escape to avoid that authentication popup.  i am expecting by escape that popup will disappear if not use appropriate keys..

Comment: @alecxe: But another authentication popup, very similar in terms of looks at least is detected by Selenium as alert. I am talking about the manager of tomcat for example. On a default installation of tomcat, if u try localhost:8080/manager u get authentication popup. Selenium detects it as alert. Also, this SO link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver) speaks about handling auth popups with Selenium and the code has an alert in it

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer, thanks, I may have to try Robot or maybe Autoit. I just wanted to understand the difference between the 2 similiar  authentication pop-ups: the one detected as alert and the one from fcb that hangs on the call I mentioned